# Import excel file to Oracle database

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, vba, odbc

I am looking to import an Excel sheet to an Oracle database.

The table has been created and the script needs to pick the Excel file from the textbox, establish odbc and import the file in the database with message box.

I tried to write the script, but I know it needs a change.

```
Private Sub IMPORT_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As    ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fileName As String
    Me.txtfile = fileName
    Dim pswd As String, strSQL As String
    pswd = "007"
    strSQL = "Insert into xyz(column1) VALUES ('&c2&')"
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
    "SERVER=company.com;User Id=xx;Password=" & pswd & ";"
    cn.Execute strSQL
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: and the error is? Your `strSQL` looks invalid. If it works, it'll only adds one value to your table. No sign related to `importing Excel Sheet`

Comment: @krishKM the error says Run-time error 91. i read somewhere Insert command would insert the rows in the database.

Comment: @krishKM, can you help in this case? I have a access utility that has a button, the expectation is when I hit the import button, the excel file selected in the textbox should import in the oracle database. Let me know if you can help

Comment: If you are using Ms Acess, you should tag `ms-access`. In Ms Access, this is pretty much easy. You need to link your oracle table and then using import service import the excel file.

Comment: I did tag accessvba, some one edited it.